# Loop on properties values in Generic List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, generics, serialization, reflection

I make an integration with one service that return data in xml.
I deserialize them into List of data using xml serialize:

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("string", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/", IsNullable = true)]
public class PositionPosting
{
   [XmlArray("JobCategories")]
   [XmlArrayItem("JobCategory", typeof(ExportItems))]
   public ExportItems[] JobCategory { get; set; }
}


[Serializable()]
public class ExportItems
{
    [XmlAttribute("key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("text")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

As result i have this:[image]

I provide the GetServiceData method the model what require to serialize into xml.

After this i create the method that will get this list like IList:

```
private void UpdateDropDown<T>(IList<DropDownModel> model, IList<T> syncData) where T : class
```

How can i get the properties and names from JobCategories Array in IList syncData?

Thanks for help!

Comment: The parameter `syncData` is just a generic collection of `T` with the only constraint of `class`, so in theory all you need to do is convert the results to an object of `List<ExportItem>` and pass them in that way surely?

Edit: If the structure is an array, using `System.Linq` will allow you to call `ToList()`.

Comment: Can you please write an example cause i'm not sure that i understand you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is slightly confusing; so here are my assumptions I can gather from reading over it a few times.

1. `GetServiceData(..)` is returning an array of `ExportItems`
2. You want to pass the information to `UpdateDropDown<T>(..)`

Now, to convert the `ExportItems[]` to `IList<ExportItem>`, you simply need to create an instance of an object that implements `IList<T>`, with the best example being `List<T>`. This can be done by first including the namespace `System.Linq`, and then "ToList'ing" the array using Linq's built in extensions, like so:

```
var data = this.GetServiceData<PositionPosting>(this.GetService(id));
UpdateDropDown(model, data[0].ToList())
```

Hope this helps. :)

Question:
What are the constraints on the `this.GetServiceData<T>(..)`?